# How to split a field value in SharePoint All Items list view

Tags: 2013, jquery, list-view, client-side-rendering

I have a SharePoint 2013 list that has a field named `ProjectCode` which contains multiple values separated by `;` . Now in the all items list view , I want to split the value at `;` and add a break line instead of `;`.

As of now I have the values as `ProjectCode1 ; ProjectCode2`

But I need to display it as    :

```
ProjectCode1
ProjectCode2
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: You can use [Client-side rendering](http://www.winwire.com/sharepoint-2013-client-side-rendering-2) and replace the ``;`` with line break e.g. ``<br />``.

Answer (score 12):

I have tested it out and was able to do it using CSR and JS Link. Save the below code to say:projectCode.js and upload it to site assets and then refer it in the JS Link of the list view :

```
  (function () {
var overrideCurrentContext = {};
overrideCurrentContext.Templates = {};
overrideCurrentContext.Templates.Fields = {
    'ProjectCode': { 'View': ProjectCode }
};
  SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCurrentContext);

function ProjectCode(ctx) { 
  var modifiedProjectCode =ctx.CurrentItem.ProjectCode.replace(";", "<br/>");
  return   modifiedProjectCode
} 
})();
```

You can remove the alert and debugger after testing it out. See the below output 
Before : 
[image]

[image]

Steps to add JS Link :

- Save the below code to projectCode.js and upload to site assets of site collection/subsite
- Go to the  list view and go to the edit page by appending "toolpaneview=2". Edit the webpart and open the 'miscellaneous' section.
- In the JSLink text box refer the JS file. If you have uploaded to the site collection's site assets, use ~sitecollection/siteassets/projectcode.js . If you have uploaded it to subsite's site assets use ~site/siteassets/projectcode.js

Comment: Dang, almost line for line had the exact same thing ready to post.  9 minutes too late!

Comment: Oops Jordan. Great Work ! Thats a photo finish.

Comment: So ProjectCode you were referring is an internal Field Name?

Comment: Yes, Its the internal name

Comment: I like the solution - I have done something like it for a customer once but using `.split(';').sort().join('<br/>')` instead of `.replace()`. **However**, there are still `debugger`-statements in your code and why (why, why...) have you defined the `function ProjectCode()` outside of your IIFE?

Comment: @Nils and why did he not bother to format the code, also mixed `"` and `'` strings

Comment: Formatted the code

Answer (score 9):

You can do it using CSR as well as using javascript. Here i'm giving simple and easy javascript solution.

**Working Javascript solution:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table[summary='YourListTitle'] td:nth-child(4)").each(function () {
        var choices = $(this).html();
        choices = choices.replace(/,/g, "<br/>");
        $(this).html(choices);
    });
});

</script>
```

1. Add script/content editor webpart on page and add above script.
2. Change summary attribute with your list title & change child number with TD number which contains your column. **(Specify list title same as showing on list view page)**

**Identify exact TD of your column:**

In your list, if check-boxes and title(with edit menu) are coming before your choice column then add two in your column position number. For example If your column position is **2** then its TD number will be **4**. see below screenshot. There are only 2 fields in my list view but my "choices" field contains in 4th TD. So check exact TD position and mention it in script. below is working example on my test site.

[image]

**Note:** This solution depends upon position of TD contains column in list view. if you change column position in view then you have to changes TD position in script.

Comment: $("table[summary='MyListName'] td:nth-child(8)").each(function () {
        var choices = $(this).html();
        choices = choices.replace(/;/g, "<br/>");
        $(this).html(choices);
    });                                                                                                                     I tried this but its not working....Its not entering into .each function

Comment: can u please share your list view screen shot. It would help us

Comment: I have updated my answer. it should help you.

Answer (score 8):

You can try CSR concept. It will be applied to the List View Web Part, so you need to following script in all the places where you are using List View Web Part (if you are) otherwise, just follow the below steps.

1. Open the List `All Items` view or the desired view.
2. Now click on gear icon and select `Edit Page`.
3. Now the page will be on edit mode, so you can select the list view web part and bring it to edit mode as well by using `Edit Web Part`.
4. Now expand the `Miscellaneous` section and scroll to bottom of that section.
5. The last property will be `JS Link`. Put the reference to JS file (will generate in a moment) in this property. Kindly note, you cannot put relative site collection/sub site url here. If you host JS file in root web then `~siteCollection/doc_Lib_name/path_to_js_file.js` if it is a sub site use `~site/doc_lib_name/path_to_js_file.js`.
6. Save the web part property, and finally save the page. That's it, you are done here.

**Code for JS File**

Following will be code you need to put in JS file and save it to document library before performing above steps. I'll recommend you to use `Site Assets` library but its completely your choice which document library you pick.

```
    var FillCtx = {};
    FillCtx.Templates = {};
    FillCtx.Templates.Fields = {'ProjectCode':{'View': fillStatus}}

    function fillStatus(ctx){
        var html ="";
        var fieldVal = ctx.CurrentItem['ProjectCode'];
        var projectCodes =[];

        if(fieldVal.indexOf(';') > 0){
            projectCodes = fieldVal.split(';');
        }else{
            projectCodes.push(fieldVal);
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < projectCodes.length; i++){
            html += projectCodes[i] + "<br/>";
        }

        return html;
    }

    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(FillCtx), 'clienttemplates.js');
```

Note: Incase if your field internal name is not `ProjectCode`, replace the ProjectCode keyword used in two places with the internal name.

Comment: No need to test `if(fieldVal.indexOf(';') > 0){` - it will work exactly the same. The code - starting from `if` to the end of `for` - can be simplyfied using `join()`. I.e. `fieldVal.split(';').join('<br/>')`. You could even filter empty values like ";;foo;bar;;baz;;;;" using `fieldVal.split(';').filter(function(x){ return !!x;}).join('<br/>')`

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. I already had CSR template so took the code from it and shaped according to the question. That time it was not in mind, to use implode or explode concept. My major focus was to give step by step guide to implement CSR unlike others how see answer and edit their own answer later on.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I had to use both the answers in 1 and 2 above for it to work with SP Online.  Possibly because some js files I've used for altering formats must be posted in [master site]/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx and uploaded as a Javascript Display Template with a specified Target Type (view, form, etc.); Standalone (Override); and Target Scope (form, View/List url) in order to work correctly (see: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-b2eedf92/view/Discussions/3 peterstilgoe's comments).  Also had to change from "," to ";" in answer 2 - and add additional functions for 6th, 7th, and 8th nth-child.  But very helpful: searched high and low for a way to split multi values in a List/View and this seemed to be the only answer for SPO.   A shame that MS doesn't address this natively somehow.